# rewriterule http://domain.com to http://www.domain.com while let other subdomains intact (like http://smt.domain.com)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have lots of 3rd tier subdomains like something.domain.com on my website.
I would like to have rewriten http://domain.com/ to http://www.domain.com/ using .htaccess without touching my 3rd tier subdomains.

All Rewriterules i found on net also rewrites my subdomains. TY for your help.

Since stackoverlow says my question doesnt meet their standards, i am puting this dummy text here....blah blah blah :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Found solution with random try

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301]
```

TY

Comment: There is no diffrence between your own answer and my answer.